# Is it possible to hack mysql_real_escape_string() Htmlspecialchars()?

Tags: php, xss, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string, htmlspecialchars

I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `Htmlspecialchars()` functions in my PHP code to make it secure against sql-injection and XSS.
Is there any possibility to hack these functions? 
If yes, can you describe how it can be done so that I can improve my code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: htmlspecialchars has absolutely **NOTHING** to do with sql injection prevent. that's why there's m_r_e_s(), and no, there's nothing that a malicious user can do to get around what it does. now, if you were using addslashes, then yes, there's a LOT you can do to completely bypass any wet-toilet-paper security system you've created with addslashes. similarly, m_r_e_s() has absolutely NOTHING to do with xss prevention. you're mixing up two totally different things.

Comment: Use htmlspecialchars just in time when echoing html, and mysql_real_escape_string just in time when outputting sql.. don't use them together

Comment: @MarcB: I once encountered a system that stored `addslashes(htmlentities(m_r_e_s($rata)))` to the database. Cargo-cult programming is painful.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1

Comment: @dcoder: if only there was a way to delete 99.99999% of the "the only php tutorial you'll ever need" pages out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP is updated try to use mysqli or PDO and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

But to answer your question, YES mysql_real_escape_string() can be injected, but it's very complicated to do so. Here's a [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do to prevent SQL injections is Using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php) and prepared statements. or at least Mysqli, as mysql is deprecated, the migration to mysqli is very very easy and it's optimized

If you use `mysql_real_escape_strings` you should be safe, as long as you escape correctly and wherever you really need it, remember that in most cases the mistake is human side, and not because of the functions :P